# Excluding sibling paths in Spring Interceptor

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-boot, interceptor

I have an interceptor "SessionInterceptor" that ensures users of my service have a session present.

I've applied this Interceptor in a class:

```
@Configuration
public class CustomConfiguration extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

public void addInterceptors(InterceptorRegistry registry) {

/*
* SessionInterceptor ensures that all requests received have a valid and
* current session ID in their header.
* 
* This interceptor applies to all paths excluding the /login and /login sub directories.
*/
InterceptorRegistration sessIDReg = registry.addInterceptor(new SessionInterceptor());
sessIDReg.addPathPatterns("/**");
sessIDReg.excludePathPatterns("/login/**");

}
```

For some reason, everytime I call either /login, /login/something, etc I always get a message from my SessionInterceptor ("No session,...").

I've tried using both the class- and method-level RequestMapping annotation, but get the same results either way.

Using www.website.com/dir1/subdir as an example, this is what I'd like to be able to do:

All dir1 paths, except for login and its subdirectories will require a session before continuing.

```
website.com/user
website.com/account
website.com/questions
```

would all have the SessionInterceptor applied to them.

```
website.com/login
website.com/login/foo
website.com/login/bar
```

would not have the SessionInterceptor applied to them.

I've gone through the various Spring documents, but haven't found anything that explains why this Interceptor isn't behaving how I'd expect it to.

=======

Edit: 2015-04-02

So I've done some more digging and found out how to enable debugging by calling --debug=TRUE when starting my JAR file.

When I try and call my */login* route, I see a debug message in the console:

```
2015-04-02 15:43:33.827 DEBUG 34012 --- [qtp671981081-20] o.s.b.a.e.mvc.EndpointHandlerMapping     : Looking up handler method for path /login
2015-04-02 15:43:33.828 DEBUG 34012 --- [qtp671981081-20] o.s.b.a.e.mvc.EndpointHandlerMapping     : Did not find handler method for [/login]
```

I found this particularly strange since I do receive output when calling */login*

At this point, I don't think the Interceptor is at fault, but instead that somehow my route isn't being declared correctly. As I mentioned in one of the comments below, I'm using Spring Boot 1.2.2.

Here's a snippet from my class that acts as a controller:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/login")
public class LoginController {


@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
@ResponseBody
public String login(){
    return "hello";
}
```

I have more methods and @RequestMappings defined, but when calling any of them I get a similar debug error about not being able to find a handler method.

I hope that this additional information will provide some clues as to what I'm doing wrong.

==========

Edit: 2015-04-02 #2

So after spending some more time debugging, it looks like */login* is being defined correctly (like I mentioned above, I get the desired output) and the interceptor is working correctly. What I realized was happening is that for some reason /error was being called after /login (I'm not sure why, however) and my Interceptor isn't excluding /error. So when I called /login, everything was going fine, but do to another call to /error, I was receiving that output.

Again, not sure why any of this is happening the way it is. I've wasted so much time with this I'm considering dumping Spring for something a little more light weight. I'd rather write my own Servlets at this point than try to figure out whatever black-magic is being performed behind the scenes.

Comment: Which spring version are you using?

Comment: Sorry, I'm using Spring version 4

Comment: Then afaik it should work, you can try upgrading to the latest 4.1 version (if you are on 4.0). Is this the only location you are registering the `SessionInterceptor`?

Comment: @M.Deinum, I should have mentioned I'm actually using Spring Boot 1.2.2. I had another interceptor that was working "correctly," or so I thought. I wasn't actually excluding any paths (which is the desired result), but I decided to try adding some. I'm actually experiencing the same issue with both Interceptors. This makes me think that I'm either defining routes wrong, or not using the Interceptors correctly.